# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin : Existing solutions not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, maven-plugin

I have tried the following solutions provided based on the questions asked here on this issue previously :

1. Project pointing to JDK instead of JRE
2. Rename classes to have Test in it .
3. Set  never
4. Delete existing .m2 file .
5. Update the Maven project on eclipse
6. Add the below dependencies in pom.xml :

   org.openrdf.sesame
       sesame-rio-api
       2.7.2

   org.apache.maven.plugins
     maven-resources-plugin
     3.0.2
     maven-plugin

   - None of the above worked and I keep the getting the same error. The test executes to pass but then no screenshots get created.

pom.xml file

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0              

  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>TestGroupID</groupId>
<artifactId>TestFrameworkCreation</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>TestFrameworkCreation</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


 <build>

<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java/Resources</directory>
  </resource>
   </resources>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.1</version>
      <configuration>

      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
       <forkMode>never</forkMode>
    </configuration>


     </plugin>

     <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>3.7.0</version>             
    </plugin>
     </plugins>

</build>



<dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.20.1</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.13.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
 </dependency>


 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.10.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.10.0</version>
   </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
    <artifactId>sesame-rio-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
 </dependency>

  </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Error :

```
  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire- 

  plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project TestFrameworkCreation: There
  are test failures.
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR] Please refer to     

  C:\Users\QQ_TT\TestFrameworkCreation\target\surefire-reports for the 

individual test results.


    [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun      [N].dump,               [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
    [ERROR] Exception in provider
    [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider
   [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:88)
  [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1107)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:955)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
 [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
 [ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 [ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 [ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR]         at Resources.MasterScript.testScreenshot(MasterScript.java:27)
[ERROR]         at TestGroupID.TestingListeners.onFinish(TestingListeners.java:20)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:772)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:741)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:509)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:206)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:160)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:83)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:84)
[ERROR]         ... 25 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: A `java.lang.NullPointerException` is coming out of `Resources.MasterScript.testScreenshot(MasterScript.java:27)`. Share your  code trial and relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: I just realized that I am trying to click on an object when the driver is already set to NULL in another script . Fixed it and the script is running. Thanks.